# Content height 100% of parent container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make **.video-wrap** height 100% of wrapper height. All I need is to make all images to be the same width and height.
The problem is that no height is specified in px in order to create responsive layout.
How make all images the same height?
I need no-js solution.

```css
body {
  background: #a1a1a1;
}
.video-wrap {} .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: inherit;
}
.video {
  width: 29.69%;
  margin: 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: gray;
}
.content {
  padding: 1.5%;
  border: 3px solid rgba(140, 139, 139, 0.6);
  background-color: black;
}
.video img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
div.desc {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="video">
      <div class="video-wrap">
        <div class="content">
          <a target="_blank" href={link}>
            <img src="" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">NY 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
      <div class="video-wrap">
        <div class="content">
          <a target="_blank" href={link}>
            <img src="https://cache-graphicslib.viator.com/graphicslib/thumbs360x240/8747/SITours/one-world-observatory-admission-in-new-york-city-224249.jpg" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">NY 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
      <div class="video-wrap">
        <div class="content">
          <a target="_blank" href={link}>
            <img src="http://cdn.ek.aero/english/images/New-York-1_tcm233-2256848.jpg" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">NY 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right, but did you try setting `min-height: 100%;` ?

Comment: Dawid Zbiński, yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**  if you can full img then change `.content`  height

```
.content
{
  padding: 1.5%;
  border: 3px solid rgba(140, 139, 139, 0.6);
  background-color: black;
  height: 80%; /* Change per. Base on requirements*/
}
```

**snippet Example**

```css
body {
  background: #a1a1a1;
}
.video-wrap {
    height: 100%;
  }
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: inherit;
}
.video {
  width: 29.69%;
  margin: 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: gray;
}
.content {
  padding: 1.5%;
  border: 3px solid rgba(140, 139, 139, 0.6);
  background-color: black;
  height: 80%;
}
.video img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
div.desc {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="video">
      <div class="video-wrap">
        <div class="content">
          <a target="_blank" href={link}>
            <img src="" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">NY 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
      <div class="video-wrap">
        <div class="content">
          <a target="_blank" href={link}>
            <img src="https://cache-graphicslib.viator.com/graphicslib/thumbs360x240/8747/SITours/one-world-observatory-admission-in-new-york-city-224249.jpg" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">NY 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
      <div class="video-wrap">
        <div class="content">
          <a target="_blank" href={link}>
            <img src="http://cdn.ek.aero/english/images/New-York-1_tcm233-2256848.jpg" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">NY 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

For adding responsiveness to the elements I always use:

```
height:auto;
width:100%;
```

When you want the height and width always be the same, your image should be like this or you have to use js in css there is no way to do that except add width and height to image proprty.
For example you can use some value for image size like this:

```
.container img
{
height:150px;
width:150px;
}
```

Comment: You should probably rewrite 'with'  to 'width' :)